# react-native VS android emulator chrome debugger error "Cannot set property 'volume' of null"

Tags: debugging, react-native

I am trying to debug react-native app running on VS emulator in chrome. The error I am getting at the moment is "Cannot set property 'volume' of null". It is like 4th or 5th cryptic error I am getting since starting, but the first one when I hit the wall. I will outline all configuration steps in case I botched something earlier:

1. Initialized project with react-native init myapp
2. Started the bundle server with react-native start --host 192.168.100.4 (the reason for host parameter is CORS error)
3. Started the app with "react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res && react-native run-android" (the reason for react-native bundle command is assets error)
4. On emulator went to shake -> Dev Settings -> Debug server host & port for device, set it to 192.168.100.4:8081 (the reason for that is "cannot connect to bundle server on localhost)
5. shake -> Debug JS Remotely
6. Chrome window opens, I hit F12. Now it still displays CORS error for a while, but after some page refreshes it displays "Cannot set property 'volume' of null" and sticks to it:

> (index):94 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'volume' of null
>       at Object.render ((index):94)
>       at Object.setState ((index):48)
>       at WebSocket.ws.onopen ((index):152)

Just in case, here is CORS error that I get initially:

> Failed to load
>   http://localhost:8081/index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://192.168.100.4:8081' is therefore not allowed
>   access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
>   mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
>   (index):188 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

It goes away after page refresh, but I wonder why it still happening.
Did anyone manage to setup Chrome Debugging with VS emulator and react-native? If so, please share your experience, all tutorials I found just happily advice to run react-native start and react-native run-android and everything should be smooth ride after that )

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17941

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with the debugger mode and was getting an error. 
I am not sure of the WHY? to that answer but the extensions in the chrome might be the problems. I disabled the extensions and I didn't get any of the errors post that.

Answer (score 0):

- Open the application
- Select DevSettings
- Choose Debug server host & port for device.
- Type your system ip address along with the port number of the metro
  builder.

For getting system ip address.

- Open command prompt
- Type ipconfig
- Select ipv4 address

Comment: I've done it 192.168.100.4 is my system ip address and the port is 8081. Didn't help unfortunately. Still this was a long time ago, maybe it is working now. Anyway, console.log is the best debugging tool :)

Comment: Just enter it as 192.168.100.4:8081